# internet explorer not working properly with fancy box

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I'm not a programmer, but I've put together a site that uses fancy box and all is good in chrome and firefox, but ie8 & ie9 are a disaster. the site is http://www.pinnaclebillboards.com.

I've searched to correct the problem but i'm not even sure how to describe it. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: have you tried loading the box without content.. any different results? that could rule out it being related to flash / content.

Answer (score 9):

You are missing the `DOCTYPE` so IE is working in quirks mode. You need to set the proper `DOCTYPE` to make fancybox to work in IE. [Check this link](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) or [this other](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) for more on this topic.

Also be sure that you close your tags properly to avoid further issues.

Comment: thanks. this fixed it, and left me with more bugs. i'm really starting to hate ie. now its loading the fancy box behind my flash. i've changed the wmode, but doesnt change anything

Comment: Set wmode to opaque in both, the object tag and the embed tag like: <param value="opaque" name="wmode"> and <embed wmode="opaque" ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and suggest it has something to do with loading a flash object into the fancybox. Shouldn't be a problem, but ya never know with IE.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source I have a few recommendations:

- Add a doctype, e.g.

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
- Change encoding to UTF-8