# FancyBox + Windows IE/FF = Fail

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a FancyBox (2.0.5) page that displays beautifully on every browser but IE and FF for Windows. I might just need some fresh eyes on it.

Here is my code:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 'type': 'iframe', 
 'width': 800, 
 'height': 580
});
```

As you can see, it's pretty basic. I'm not using any helpers, nor have I modified the default CSS.

On every Mac browser, and Chrome for PC, I get this:

[image]

Which is exactly what I should get (although I could do without the scrollbars).

On IE 7 & 8 (haven't tried 9) and FF for Windows, I get this:

[image]

No frame, no background, and no close button. Also, you can't close it; you have to refresh.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is a link: http://www.downtownmuncie.org/business/search2/arts/ You'll want to click on the "Zoom Map" link under the smaller map.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011549/internet-explorer-not-working-properly-with-fancy-box

Comment: Nope. My DOCTYPE  is set to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` and my  character encoding is set to utf-8.

Comment: So  it is, Linuxios. The client sent me that. It worked fine in FF for me.

Comment: Corrected error in question. It does not, in fact, work in FF for Windows. My bad, and thanks to Linuxios for pointing  it out.

Comment: so, is the question answered? if not, it would be great if you can share a link where we can see the issue if FF and track down the cause of it.

Comment: Here is a link: http://www.downtownmuncie.org/business/search2/arts/

Comment: You'll want to click on the "Zoom Map" link under the smaller map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many things you need to fix in your website if you want to make fancybox workable (and most probably other stuff too.)

**First**, line 153 and 154 : you are loading 2 instances of fancybox when you actually need a single one

```
<script src="http://www.downtownmuncie.org/s/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.downtownmuncie.org/s/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

choose any of them, but not both.

**Second**, the real problem of your issue is the line 155

```
<link href="http://www.downtownmuncie.org/s/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/javascript" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Notice that you have `type="text/javascript"` and `type="text/css"` and this why the fancybox css file cannot be loaded so it displays weirdly (copy and paste can be so dangerous.) Remove `type="text/javascript"` from that line AND it is also advisable to move it to the `<head>` section of your document.

**Third**, line number 4

you have and extra double quote " so your document has no character encoding information; this part:

```
content="text/html; charset="utf-8"
```

should be

```
content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

if you can find the difference (hint: all goes as the `content` value)

**Fourth and last**, line 158

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
 'type': 'iframe', 
 'width': 800, 
 'height': 580
});
</script>
```

wrap your script within the `.ready()` method like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
  'type': 'iframe', 
  'width': 800,
  'height': 580
 });
});
</script>
```

That is documented by the way http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

It is also advisable to use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check and fix all your little html coding bugs.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for both a thorough answer, and a professional delivery. I'm embarrassed at having made so many rookie mistakes, but that's what happens when you rush through your work. I almost wish other browsers weren't so forgiving. I might have caught those errors sooner. Thanks again!